Google Sheets - How to SUMIF of splitted text?
Let's say I have the two following tables:



Team
Goal scored




Team A
X


Team B
Y






Home team
Away team
Result




Team A
Team B
3-1


Team B
Team A
1-0


Team A
Team B
1-1


Team B
Team A
0-4



How can I calculate X and Y?
I need a formula to populate the Goal scored column, that:

Splits the Result column into two numbers using the "-" separator
Sums the first value of the splitted string IF the home team is equal to the current row of the Team column
Sums the second value of the splitted string IF the away team is equal to the current row of the Team column
Sums the two sums obtained at points 2 and 3

So in this example X is equal to 3+0+1+4 = 8, and Y is equal to 1+1+1+0 = 3
Thank you
I've tried something like
=sumif(B110:B1000;$B103;index(split(D110:D1000;"-");;1)) but it returns an error

Result of a Split
A split will result on an array which is not allowed to be processed on a SumIf. I suggest utilizing MAP Function and Sum instead.
Try this
=BYROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B5)), LAMBDA(z, SUM(CHOOSECOLS(LET(x,HSTACK(TOCOL(A2:B5),TOCOL(BYROW(C2:C5, LAMBDA(r,IFERROR(SPLIT(r,"-"),SPLIT("0-0","-")))))), FILTER(x, CHOOSECOLS(x,1) =z)),2))))

Sample Output:

Reference:
MAP
HSTACK

Thanks a lot for your answer, but it's not quite working for two reasons:

Some values returns the error about the value 1 of the split function being empty
The formula you provided returns a matrix. Instead I want to set X and Y much like a vlookup would do, so directly populating the related cells


I understand, I can adjust the formula to provide the x,y. Give it a try and let me know if the issue still persist.

I also updated the formula to cater your issues in case there is no value on the score part of things.  Please let me know if I have missed some occurrence on your dataset that wasn't part of the sample dataset.


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=reduce(;C:C;lambda(a;c;a+iferror(index(split(c;"-");xmatch(E2;offset(c;;-2;;2))))))



Assuming your source table starts at A1, you can generate the entire result table in one formula alongside it or on another tab like this:
=arrayformula(query(
{tocol(A2:B;;1)\tocol(split(C2:C;"-");;1)};
"select Col1,sum(Col2) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1 
label Col1 'Team', sum(Col2) 'Goals scored'";0))

We are using tocol and array literals to 'unroll' the team and goal data into a flat table, then query to summarise it as required.
